# Converting a page created with panel into PDF

Tags: 7, panels

I'm working on D7 Panels and I created few pages using panel. I have a use case to generate the pdf for the data existed in the panel rather than the whole page with header and footer. Are there any recommendations to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, dowload [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print), patch module with [Can Panel pages be sent to PDF for rendering?](https://www.drupal.org/project/print/issues/565856), download [wkhtmltopdf libary](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf), place it under /sites/all/libraries, and configure your module like: [image], and inside panels add print PDF widget like:[image], done!.

EDIT: today 7/7/2020 panles 7 had an upgrade, be carefull, i think patch apply to an older version in panels.

Comment: Hi @pinueve Thanks for quick response. Patch [#39](https://www.drupal.org/project/print/issues/565856) does not worked with  [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module. Can you please let me know the version of the print module which work with #39 patch. I am using print 7.x-2.2 version which patch suites for this.

Comment: print module: Version: 7.x-2.2

Comment: I am using the same module but its giving me patch [error](https://github.com/an-snatcher/errors/blob/master/print%20error)